# How window services work internally compared to task scheduler or task manager?

Tags: c#, windows-services, taskmanager, taskscheduler

I am a .net developer working in web applications and from past few months I started working on windows applications and one application need to run every day at 12 noon so I wrote a web service with the help of google and it is working fine.

But I am just wondering how windows services work.
I read lot of posts and not one have answered my question.So coming forward in my own words.

According to my understanding in web service I create a scheduler using timer that runs all 24 hours and will execute the necessary code when the timer condition is met.

In scheduler I configure a scheduler that runs an application(which is a service in previous case) when the time condition is met.

Now my questions:

1. Regarding RAM usage?

   I know services utilizes RAM. But considering if my code is heavy like lets consider 10mb. Ther fore .exe file will be around 10mb or more. So when service starts does it utilizes 10mb of RAM all 24 hours or it will just create just scheduler in service which will be pretty small and then loads service code when the time is met?

   Considering scheduler how does it work. I think there will be a trigger that is fired when time is met and fired trigger will execute .exe file generically let me call it a service(but it is a application). So here the service code is separated from scheduler so only scheduler runs and loads service code into RAM.

Am I right?
Does scheduler also runs all 24 hours checking time?

2. If in case I have 2 services with one installer. Now there will be 2 servises installed. But I would like to know if both services is of 10mb each which makes 20 mb .exe size and when both services starts running does there sizes be of 10 mb each(considering it will lode relative service code) or 20 mb each(considering it will lode both service codes because they are in same exe).

Hoping for some valuable answered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need some code to run just once a day - you don't need a service at all, just use windows task scheduler to run your .exe (console application).

Comment: Yes. I understand that. But that's not my question. My question is not which should I choose. My question is how they work differently in the terms of Memory, RAM and logic of execution of code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on your implementation.

This is how a windows service works:

1. Your installer registers a windows service object
2. The service object starts `yourservice.exe`
3. Within `yourservice.exe` you have to implement the service commands (e. g.: `OnStart`, `OnStop`)
4. Now it depends on you what to do in these methods
5. `yourservice.exe` runs as long as the service is running

My recommendations:

1. Pack your existing logic into a library
2. Start the timer in the service `OnStart` method (the timer needs almost no ressources)
3. In the timer callback instantiate your logic using the library (now your 10 megs are allocated)
4. Clean up everything after your work has been completed (the 10 megs get freed, if you don't use anything persistently)

In step 3 you are free to instantiate your logic twice which will use 2x 10 megs then, of course.